# Optimize many SQL request in 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a little question, i have thse 3 SQL requests, and i want to know if it's possible to optimize them in 1 request.

My 3 sql request:

```
SELECT FAI, COUNT( FAI ) AS deferred_count
FROM  `email_errors` 
WHERE STATUS =1
GROUP BY FAI
-------------------------------------------
SELECT FAI, COUNT( FAI ) AS sent_count
FROM  `email_errors` 
WHERE STATUS =0
GROUP BY FAI
-------------------------------------------
SELECT FAI, COUNT( FAI ) AS Bounced_count
FROM  `email_errors` 
WHERE STATUS =2
GROUP BY FAI
```

So if it's possible, i try to get one output table with 4 column result `FAI|deferred_count|sent_count|bounced_count`

i don't know if it's possible to make a join by 'FAI' on the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT FAI, 
       sum( status = 0 ) AS send_count,
       sum( status = 1 ) AS deferred_count,
       sum( status = 2 ) AS Bounced_count
FROM  `email_errors` 
GROUP BY FAI
```

Comment: +1 but you should use `WHERE status IN (0,1,2)` so it doesn't scan a the whole table. It could be that other status values account for 99% of the table.

Comment: Thank you @BillKarwin Yes you'r right but i only have those three status, so it's not necessary to add it.

Comment: @Ahmadhc, fair enough, then that's all right. I just try not to make such assumptions. :-)